# How to Add custom field/property to modal in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

I am calculating a total field from database query but it is not a model property or database field. After query execution, how  can I bind that total model, as I have to return the list of model to display in  table.
thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a view model that contains an additional property for the total.

Comment: Thanks   Stephen Muecke ..  I am new to mvc

Answer (score 0):

You can use Viewmodel. Everytime you have to choose to use ViewModel.Because after a while you need concat model or validate message.
I'm adding basic example view model.

```
public class EmployeeViewModel 
{
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name required")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last name required")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public decimal PersonelSalary {get;set;}
}
```

Using this view model you can define the view (Razor view engine):

```
@model SolutionName.Models.ViewModels.EmployeeViewModel
```